# Arrays inside structs in C

Tags: c++, memory-management

I´m struggling to understand this concept: I have a fixed size definition:

(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aa931918.aspx)

```
typedef struct _FlashRegion {
  REGION_TYPE regionType;
  DWORD dwStartPhysBlock;
  DWORD dwNumPhysBlocks;
  DWORD dwNumLogicalBlocks;
  DWORD dwSectorsPerBlock;
  DWORD dwBytesPerBlock;
  DWORD dwCompactBlocks;
} FlashRegion, *PFlashRegion;
```

this FlashRegion struct, is used in this another struct:
(from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aa932688.aspx)

```
typedef struct _FlashInfoEx {
  DWORD cbSize;
  FLASH_TYPEflashType;
  DWORD dwNumBlocks;
  WORD dwDataBytesPerSector;
   DWORD dwNumRegions;
  FlashRegion region[1]; 
} FlashInfoEx, *PFlashInfoEx;
```

The problem is, I can have a variable number of FlashRegions inside a FlashInfoEx. The function that I´m debugging does this somewhere in the code:

```
 memcpy (pFlashInfoEx->region,  g_pStorageDesc->pRegionTable,
         g_pStorageDesc->dwNumRegions *  sizeof(FlashRegion));
```

That means that it copies an amount of regions to pFlashInfoEx (that I pass in the call of the function);

So, the code will overwrite memory if dwNumRegions is bigger than one. If that is the case, Should I create a FlashRegion [FIXED_SIZE] in my code and somehow place/overwrite in FlashInfoEx->region? How do I do that?

Thanks, 
Marcelo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The concept is while FlashRegion looks like a fixed size structure, it is actually dynamically sized. The magic is done when allocating the structure - instead of calling `(FlashRegion*)malloc(sizeof(FlashInfoEx))` or `new FlashRegion`, you call something like `(FlashRegion*)malloc(sizeof(FlashInfoEx)+sizeof(FlashRegion)*(numRegions-1))`

Comment: Wow, you guys are fast here!

So, that implies that region should always be the last member of the struct right? Depending of the compiler, isn't this a risk?

Comment: When defining structs to be able to interact with any API you need to be able to define exact memory layout of the structure. I think standard requires struct members to be ordered in the order specified, but it does not specify alignment. In practice all compilers provide alignment control as well.

Comment: Yes, the region must be last. Risk? Only in the sense that C itself is risky. This is in fact how the language was intended to be used. There is a reason that modern languages make this impossible, but that doesn't retroactively rip the design pattern out of the C89 and C90 toolkit.

Comment: In C++, it is very risky, yes. It doesn't play nice with non-POD types, copy constructors and such. But in C, it's a fairly common trick.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly common C idiom for variably sized structures.  In order to make this work, you need to ensure you allocate enough memory for the array size you want, usually something like

```
pFlashInfoEx = malloc(offsetof(PFlashInfoEx, region) + g_pStorageDesc->dwNumRegions *  sizeof(FlashRegion));
```

this interacts badly with trying to use 'new' in C++; you have to allocate the memory manually:

```
void *mem = ::operator new(offsetof(PFlashInfoEx, region) + g_pStorageDesc->dwNumRegions *  sizeof(FlashRegion));
pFlashInfoEx = new(mem) PFlashInfoEx;
for (int i = 1; i < g_pStorageDesc->dwNumRegions; i++)
    new (&pFlashInfoEx->region[i]) FlashRegion;
```

Answer (score 1):

The interace that you are using is using the *struct hack*. This means that you need to manually dynamically allocate enough storage for the structure as if it was declared with region being an array of more than 1 `FlashRegion`.

For this interface, it needs to be enough space for at least and array of `dwNumRegions` `FlashRegion`s.

Something like `offsetof(FlashInfoEx, region) + sizeof FlashRegion * n` bytes where `n` is a number that you need to subsequently pass to `FMD_GetInfoEx` or whatever function you are using.

Answer (score 0):

...see [this answer on legacy design patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365276/this-compiles-without-a-warning-in-vc9-at-warning-level-4-why-would-one-not-cons/1365341#1365341) using a simple example in a previous question.